# How to insert multiple data into database with php

Tags: php, mysql, insert

**UPDATE:**

How to insert multiple data into database?
I have Product tabel with 3 fields. status int 1, id_product varchar 10, and name_product varchar 30.
Here is my code:

```
<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='5'>
<tr>
  <th>STATUS</th>
  <th>PRODUCT ID</th>
  <th>PRODUCT NAME</th>
  <th>CHOOSE</th>
</tr>

<?php
  include "connect.php";
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE IDCUSTOMER = $_SESSION[IDCUSTOMER]";
  $query = mysql_query($sql);
  while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  echo"<td><select name='status'><option value='0'>BUY</option>
  <option value='1'>SELL</option>
  <option value='2'>LOAN</option>
  </select></td>
  <td>$result[id_product]</td>
  <td>$result[name_product]</td>
  <td><input type='checkbox' name='check' /></td>";
  }
?>
</table>
```

The data that I want to insert into database is status, id_product, and name_product.

I want to insert this multiple data when checkbox is checked.
I have don't know how to insert them.
I hope anyone here can help me :-).
I really appreciates any help.

Comment: seems like you are only retrieving information from the database. where is the code that is supposed to insert data?

Comment: Question is unclear. Lack of codes.

Comment: @RST that is my question. how can to insert that data because it have a multiple data. Any suggest

Comment: code to insert the data does not exist. That's what I want to ask how to insert multiple data, @NanaPartykar

Answer (score 2):

That won't work - you would have one `select` / `check` parameter per result, so you can't tell where it belongs after you post the (missing) `<form>`, since all you get is a single `$_REQUEST['check']` with value `on` and a single `$_REQUEST['status']` with a value `0`, `1` or `2`.

Also, `$result[id_product]` should be `{$result['id_product']}` etc.

If you name your fields like this, including the product ID, you will be able to know to which product the `check` and `status` values apply:

```
$prod_id = $result['id_product'];
echo "
  <select name='status-{$prod_id}' ...>
  <input name='check-{$prod_id}' ...>
";
```

you can then process them server-side like this:

```
foreach ( $_REQUEST as $k => $v )
   if ( preg_match( "@^check-(.*)@", $k, $m ) )      
   {
       $id_product = $m[1];
       $status = $_REQUEST[ "status-$id_product" ];
       // your INSERT query...
   }
```

or, without `preg_match`, you'd check if `strpos( $k, "check-" ) === 0` and `substr( $k, strlen( "check-" ) )` to get the product id.

**Alternative: Arrays**

PHP offers another way to pass request parameters so that they end up as an array: you can name the inputs `a[b]`, for example:

```
  <input name='a[foo]' value='abc'/>
  <input name='a[bar]' value='def'/>
```

If you submit this form and then

```
echo "<pre>" . print_r( $_REQUEST, 1 ) . "</pre>";
```

you will see

```
 Array
 (
     [a] => Array
     (
         [foo] => abc
         [bar] => def
     )
 )
```

That means that you can access those inputs as an array: `$_REQUEST['a']['foo']`.

You can also do this:

```
  <input name='a[]' value='abc'/>
  <input name='a[]' value='def'/>
```

in which case `$_REQUEST` is

```
 Array
 (
     [a] => Array
     (
         [0] => abc
         [1] => def
     )
 )
```

**The Form**

Now let's apply this to your form.

I'm taking this opportunity to introduce you to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) since `mysql_query` etc. is deprecated. You could use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), but if you change databases you'd have to change a lot of code; with PDO you'd simply change the connection string.

Also it's wise to use query parameters / parameter binding. The query

```
"SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE IDCUSTOMER = $_SESSION[IDCUSTOMER]";
```

has two related problems: First, `$_SESSION[IDCUSTOMER]` should be `{$_SESSION['IDCUSTOMER']}`, otherwise you'd get a warning and the query will be `".. WHERE IDCUSTOMER = "` - a syntax error.
Second, if `$_SESSION['IDCUSTOMER']` is not an integer, the query will also have a syntax error.

```
// connect to the database (connect.php)
$db = new PDO( "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_db", $dbuser, $dbpass );

// query for products using ? placeholders for query parameters:
$sth = $db->prepare( "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE IDCUSTOMER = ?" );
$sth->execute( [ $_SESSION['IDCUSTOMER'] ] );

while ( $row = $sth->fetch() ) {
  $id_product = $result['id_product'];  // makes things easier below
  echo "
    <tr>
      <td>
          <select name='status[$id_product]'>
            <option value='0'>BUY</option>
            <option value='1'>SELL</option>
            <option value='2'>LOAN</option>
          </select>
      </td>
      <td> $id_product </td>
      <td> {$row['name_product']} </td>
      <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check[$id_product]' /> </td>
  ";
}
```

Here you see we're using the `foo[bar]` notation for HTTP request parameter names rather than the `foo[]` notation. This is because if we use `<select name='status[]'>` and `<input type='checkbox' name='check[]'>`, then it can happen that `count( $_REQUEST['status']) != count( $_REQUEST['check'] )`, because a checkbox parameter is only submitted if it is checked, and absent otherwise.

It's also important to use the `$result['id_product']` and not simply a row-index (`$i++`), because the order and number of rows that is returned by the query can change between generating the `<form>` and submitting it.

**Processing the form**

This is very similar to the earlier `foreach ($_REQUEST` snippet, but simpler because we use the `foo[bar]` syntax for request parameters:

```
$sth = $db->prepare( "
  INSERT INTO PRODUCTS (id_product, name_product, status, IDCUSTOMER ) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
");

foreach ( $_REQUEST['check'] as $id_product => $ignore )
    $sth->execute( [ 
        $id_product, 
        $name_product, // TODO
        $status,
        $_SESSION['IDCUSTOMER']
    ] );
```

Comment: This code works for what?
<select name='status-{$result['id_product']}' ...>
<input name='check-{$result['id_product']}' ...>

Comment: @Kenney.So, it will be like this?
foreach ( $_REQUEST as $k => $v )
   if ( preg_match( "@^check-(.*)@", $k, $m ) )
   {
       $id_product = $m[1];
       $status = $_REQUEST[ "status-$id_product" ];
       Insert into product (status,id_product,name_product) values ($status,$id_product,$name_product)
   }

Comment: Something like that, but where does `$name_product` come from? What are you trying to do exactly? Your table shows *existing* products, and you'll be adding those products to the table *again* - shouldn't that give errors when `id_product` is unique? If, for instance, you simply want to update those products with the new status, you should use an `UPDATE` query (I've seen others confused between UPDATE and INSERT, so I'm just making sure..)

Comment: I'll explain what i'm trying to do @Kenny.
First, showing all of the data from product table which contain status, id product, and name product like in the table above.
Second, when all of the data has been shown I choose which product that what I want and check the checkbox.
Third, save all  of the data into database.

$name_product is just variabel for name product value.that i given.
Yes I'll be adding those products to the table again so i make the id_product not unique.
What does your opinion?

Comment: Okay, thanks for explaining. Then you got it - it's basically just looping over all checked checkboxes and doing an INSERT query for each product. I'll be happy to help you to get it to work if you run into trouble.

Comment: I have this following array code: <input type="text" id="id$i" name="name$i" /> And I want to insert them into database with POST method. I put $i after id to create unique id. I make $i from for loop with $i = 1; $i++. So, the result will be like this: <input type="text" id="id1" name="name1" /> <input type="text" id="id2" name="name2" /> etc. So, my question is what can I do if I want to insert this data with POST method.? Pleasee help @Kenney

Comment: Thanks for helping me, @Kenney